# How to quickly search through on a very large database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I try through CodeIngiter make queries as quickly as possible on a table that contains approximately 1.200.000 of records ...

I have created 3 indexes on name , tags and categories

```
*/

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for videos
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `videos`;
CREATE TABLE `videos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `categories` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `embed` tinytext,
  `description` text,
  `tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hd` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `likes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `dislikes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `cover` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `mega_search` (`name`,`tags`,`categories`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1273355 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But the response is too long =>
Total Execution Time    7.0999 for this query

```
SELECT *
FROM `videos`
WHERE `categories` LIKE '%Reality%' ESCAPE '!'
ORDER BY `id` DESC
 LIMIT 20
```

Comment: `LIKE '%Reality%'` can't use indexes and will be tremendously slow at scale. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html, or index it with something like Lucene.

Comment: 1.2 million rows can hardly be called as a very large database

Comment: @Lamak Anything's a large database when you're doing `LIKE '%Reality%'` :-p

Comment: I suspect you are storing your categories as a delimited string list.  That is the wrong approach.  If you had another table with one row per `video` and `category`, then your query would be much easier to optimize.

Comment: Ok i have understood , but how i can count the rows of my query  ?

Comment: I have replace the like per a where , i have the same result (time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments mention, your predicate `LIKE '%Reality%'` cannot be optimized with a conventional index. You need to use a full-text search solution.

I wrote a presentation about this:

- Slides: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql
- Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Sa7TvXnQwY